# Print Generated XpsDocument object without saving it to disk

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, xps

I'm trying to print some generated XPS documents, using WPF.
so far I got this code:

```
        XpsDocumentWriter dw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue);
        dw.Write(xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence());
```

but it fails at runtime claiming that the document provided has its URI set to null. That's obvious since I generated it at runtime and it lives in memory.
Is there a way to turn this document into a Visual or to print it somehow?

EDIT: Here are the steps for printing some XPS file from disk: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772.aspx